# Lattice deformation shrinks geometry

Tags: modifiers, lattice

My mesh shrink if the lattice is transformed, even if all lattice points are only rotated and maintain their relative distances.

[image]

Is there any way to *enhance* the lattice performance?

Comment: I suppose it's how lattice works. Try subdividing it  so the corner subdivision of lattice correlates with the corner of the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more *subdivisions* in X and Y resolves the issue.

It doesn't matter if the **Outside** property is checked or not.

[image]